# MTB size for a tall guy

Tags: mountain-bike, size, specialized-bikes, tall

I'm out looking for a new full suspension XC bike. I've had an Epic 3-4 years ago. I've had a little break until now. Normally I would choose a size XL any day, but I've seen some pro's sizing down. The thing is, it's really hard to find the bikes I want in size XL. I can find some nice S-Works in size large used though. They rarely go on sale in XL.

I'm 197 cm tall and weigh 80 kg.

My question is, is it possible to modify with different stem, saddle position, and height on the seat post, to make it right on a size large?

Comment: IMO No for Specialized. I’m 182cm and ride a large 2016 Stumpjumper. I wished I’d bought the XL in retrospect as the position is a little upright even with an offset bushing to kick the head back an extra 0.5 degree.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your quick reply!

Comment: Try talking to your LBS - they tend to focus on S/M/L and the XS and XL sizes just don't get brought in.  If you have a serious interest they can get one on trial from the wholesaler at no cost to them.  Frankly a too-small bike with long parts is a compromise and if you're buying new, buy the bike you need not some short-changed "whatever is in stock" answer.   (I'm your height and I break small frames at the seatpost clamp)

Comment: The issue is that I can't get any XL Specialized Epic in the model I want. They just dont have it. Its not to be found unfortunately :-(